# Angular 2 Testing: "Can't find variable: Headers" when testing with PhantomJS but works fine with Chrome

Tags: angular, unit-testing, google-chrome, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

My team and I have recently started building a project using angular-cli 1.1.1 (angular 4.1.3) and we are incorporating the [in-memory-web-api](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api) from angular.io's tour of heroes to mock out http calls until our api is constructed.  I was able to get all of our karma unit tests to pass successfully using chrome but due to CI limitations wanted to try and get karma running with PhantomJS.  When switching over from chrome to phantomJS a few tests fail specifying the error message:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) UserDataService should be created FAILED
    ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Headers in http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.bundle.js (line 693)
```

Here is what my **user-data.service.ts** file looks like:

```
import {Injectable} from @angular/core";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/add/operator/catch";
import "rxjs/add/operator/toPromise";
import "rxjs/add/operator/find";
import {User} from "../data-objects/user";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class UserDataService {
  private userDataUrl = `api/userData`;
  private headers = new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/json"});
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getUser(id:number): Observable<User> {
    const url = `${this.userDataUrl}/?id=${id}`;
   return this.http.get(url, this.headers)
      .map(response => {
        return  response.json().data as User;
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error("An error occurred in the user data service.", error);
    return Promise.reject(error.json().error || "Server Error in UserDataServer")
  }
}
```

I have tried searching the web for a solution but thus far haven't been able to figure out why phantomJS can't find the Headers but chrome can.  For completeness sake here is my karma.conf.js and user-data.service.spec.ts files respectively.  Any help would be appreciated.

**karma.conf.js**

```
  module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      config: './angular-cli.json',
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
              ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul']
              : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
    autoWatch: true,
    // browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    // browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

**user-data.service.spec.ts**:

```
import {TestBed, inject} from '@angular/core/testing';

import {UserDataService} from './user-data.service';
import {Http, BaseRequestOptions} from "@angular/http";
import {MockBackend} from "@angular/http/testing";


describe('UserDataService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [UserDataService,
        MockBackend,
        BaseRequestOptions,
        {provide: Http}]
    });
  });

  fit('should be created', inject([UserDataService], (service: UserDataService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer to this after going through the main.bundle.js file where the error was occurring.  Using intellij to manage the imports for me I realized that Headers was being pulled in from `lib.es6.d.ts` rather than from `@angular/http`.  Once I included the Headers import from angular all of my tests that were failing in phantomJS started passing.

Comment: There really isn't any code to show, the issue I was experiencing was related to importing the wrong class called Header.  I was importing from lib.es6.d.ts rather than @angular/http.  I fixed this by correcting the import statement so it looked like:

import {Headers, Http} from "@angular/http"; rather than import {Http} from "@angular/http";

My IDE was automatically importing the ES6 class called Header which I didn't notice until after posting the question.

Comment: Ok I see. I dont even  use that but I got the warning abot. anyway thanks for your response